# Using a dropdown box for selecting stateprovice?

Tags: civicrm-entity, angular

I'm trying to change some forms from quickforms to angularjs.
In quickforms you do this:
$this->addEntityRef('Location_province', ts('Select Province'),
['entity' => 'state_province',]);

How do I replicate this in Angularjs?  This is what I thought I should do but probably a class or something in CRM to already do this:
In js file:

```
provinces = crmApi('state_province', 'get', {
      country_id: 1039,
    })
// do I process provinces to get to the values I want?
this.province = provinces
var ctrl = this
```

In the html template file I have:

```
<div crm-ui-field="{name: 'myForm.location_province', title: ts('Province'),}">
            <select
              crm-ui-select="{allowClear: true}"
              ng-model="$ctrl.myContact.location_province"
              multiple="single"
              class="big"
            >
              <option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.province.values" value="{{option.name}}">
              {{option.name}}
            </option>
            </select>
            {{myform.location_province}}
          </div>
```

So its not working because the crmApi returns it in an array of multiple levels so is there a class to do this for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
<div crm-ui-field="{name: 'myForm.location_province', title: ts('Province')}">
  <input
    name="myForm.location_province" crm-ui-id="myForm.location_province" 
     crm-entityref="{entity: 'state_province', api: {params: {country_id: 1039, is_active: 1, options:{sort:\'name\'}}}, select: {allowClear: true, minimumInputLength: 0, placeholder: ts(\'Select State\')}}"
    ng-model="myForm.location_province"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for.